# The HDD isn’t shown in Ubuntu terminal and disk utility application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, bios

▼ My Environment

1. OS : Ubuntu 20.04 in SSD (I also tested Ubuntu 22.04)
2. Hard Disk : Western Digital Hard Disk 10TB (model : WUS721010ALE6L4)
3. Main Board : supported AHCI technology.

▼ My Problem

When I have connected a Hard Disk to a PC, Bios(UEFI) well recognizes it.
The model number of the hard disk is correctly displayed on the Bios screen.

But the HDD isn’t shown by the `sudo fdisk -l` command in terminal. Also, Disk utility application does not show the HDD, so that I cannot format it.

▼ My prediction

I guess the following three cases.

1. Ubuntu doesn’t recognize my hard disk because it’s 10TB.
2. Ubuntu doesn’t recognize the hard disk because it is on a motherboard on which a technology called AHCI is applied.
3. If you go to the WD homepage, there are drivers for Windows and Mac, but there is no driver for Ubuntu(Linux). Special driver to install?

How can I figure out a solution to this problem?
Thank you for your time and opinion.

Comment: Get the Western Digital drive test app on a bootable USB and check the entire drive for errors.

Comment: Check whether lspci -k shows that a driver is being used the your SATA/AHCI controller (or whether it is listed at all). Also check dmesg for any relevant error.

Comment: And please post the actual brand/model of the motherboard.

Comment: @TomYan
I tested ‘dmesg’, and the result was several similar lines like “ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)”.
Note: There was the same error not only on ata1 but also ata3, 6, 5, 8, 4 etc....
I'm sorry but do you know solution of this error?